# Show php file every after 10 post using php

Tags: php

I want to show a file on every 10 posts in my infinite scroll.

When user scroll down then the following code working:

```
if(isset($_POST['postID']) ? $_POST['postID'] : ''){
    $lastPostID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['postID']); 
    $newsarray=$Post->Posts($uid, $lastPostID);  
    if($newsarray){
        $r=0; 
        $show_hashTags = false;
        foreach($newsarray as $PostFromData) { 
            include("../contents/posts.php");
            $r = $r + 1; 
            include("../contents/show.php");   
            $show_hashTags = true; 
         } 
    } 
 }
```

and i want to show this file every after 10 post when infinite scroll appeared.

**show.php**

```
<?php 
if ($r % 9 == 0 && $show_hashTags) {
     // Show trending hashtags.
} 
?>
```

but show.php is not appearing after 10 posts. Wat i am missing here anyone can help me please ?

Comment: I think you would be better off when you would have it as an method that you can call out rather than including the page all the time

Comment: wouldn't it better to modify the query than getting all the results and modulo?

Comment: @Robert you are right i will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `show.php` never receives an `$r` that is `0`.  If you want every 10, then change your modulus number.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/OV6X9):

```
for ($r = 1; $r < 25; ++$r) {
    echo "$r: ";
    if ($r % 10 == 0) {
        echo "Yes\n";
    } else {
        echo "No\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1: No
2: No
3: No
4: No
5: No
6: No
7: No
8: No
9: No
10: Yes
11: No
12: No
13: No
14: No
15: No
16: No
17: No
18: No
19: No
20: Yes
21: No
22: No
23: No
24: No
```

---

p.s. `if(isset($_POST['postID']) ? $_POST['postID'] : ''){`  <-- this is weird, just use `if(isset($_POST['postID'])) {`

Also, write `if ($r % 10 == 0 && $show_hashTags) {` around your `include` call (or as WKoppel suggests, find a clean way to perform the repeated task -- a method is a good idea).

And `$r = $r + 1;` can be more briefly written as `++$r`.

---

Full Implementation... (could definitely be refined further with more intimate knowledge of the project)

```
if (isset($_POST['postID'])) {
    $lastPostID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['postID']); 
    $newsarray = $Post->Posts($uid, $lastPostID);  
    if ($newsarray) {
        $r = 0; 
        // $show_hashTags = false;
        foreach ($newsarray as $PostFromData) { 
            include("../contents/posts.php");
            ++$r; 
            if ($r % 10 == 0) {
                include("../contents/show.php");
            }
            // $show_hashTags = true; 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185490/discussion-on-answer-by-mickmackusa-show-php-file-every-after-10-post-using-php).